# How to make a DT datatable row selection sticky in an R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

The rows in a table may dynamically change, but existing row selections by a user should remain. Selected rows are stored by their row index, so when a new `datatable()` is rendered, how do you retain the selected rows?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the solution. First the `selection` parameter in `datatable()` can take a list of the form `list(mode='multiple', selected=c(1,3))`

The second part is to determine what selected rows remain in the new table. 
One solution to the second part is to store a copy of the datatable as a session variable. When a new datatable is generated, the old table is compared with the new. A new set of selected row indices is computed based on the common rows in the old and new tables. The row indices into the new table are found by using a `which(newkeys %in% oldkeys)` idiom.

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput('yellow.only', 'Yellow Only'),
  uiOutput('fruit.selection'),
  DT::dataTableOutput("dt.fruit.selection")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  fruit.options <- reactive({
    all.fruits <- c(grape='Grape', banana='Banana', papaya='Papaya', raspberry='Raspberry')
    yellow.fruits <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
    all.fruits[yellow.fruits | !input$yellow.only]
  })

  fruit.options.df <- reactive({
    data.frame(fruits=fruit.options(), some.other.col=nchar(fruit.options()))
  })

  output$fruit.selection <- renderUI({ selectInput('fruit', 'Fruit', choices=fruit.options(), selected=input$fruit, multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE, size=length(fruit.options())) })

  output$dt.fruit.selection <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (!exists('fruit.options.cache') || identical(fruit.options.cache, fruit.options.df())) {
        rows.selected <- isolate(input$dt.fruit.selection_rows_selected)
    } else {
      rows.selected <- which(fruit.options.df()$fruit %in% fruit.options.cache$fruits[isolate(input$dt.fruit.selection_rows_selected)])
    }

    fruit.options.cache <<- fruit.options.df()
    DT::datatable(fruit.options.cache, rownames=FALSE, selection=list(mode="multiple", selected=rows.selected))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This can also be run from RStudio with `shiny::runGist("https://gist.github.com/dkulp2/7ebb1c936d08f3434127e58d7798af28")`